# Fix time zone in countries thats add and subtract one hour when is summer or winter

Tags: go

i have this problem, there is a system thats has the duty to deliver a message in the future in a certain date, like a time limit, so this system is in another country thats have the time zone -4 hours and the country thats recibe the message is in a time zone -3 hours, for this country are Chile and Brazil, the problem is, this countries when they enter to the summer time they add one hour, but in different dates, for a period of time like 4 months thy have the same time zone, so for me to deliver the message in the right time i have to add one hour to the date in when the time zone are in -4 and - 3 but when the time zone match -3 hours i dont have to do nothing.

for this task i want to use the function `time.LoadLocation("America/Sao_Paulo")`, but reading the documentation dosen't mention if they fix the time zone when this countries change their time zone.

does anyone know if they adjust the time zone, or know another function thats can work in this situation?

Comment: Why don't you store everything in UTC? When I set a time to deliver the message, get this time's UTC and store this instead of local time. Then set the server's time also to UTC (or take this time in account in your Go server) and deliver the message this way.

Answer (score 1):

Areas that observe daylight savings time don’t change the time *zone*, they change the time *standard*. For instance, Los Angeles observes a given time eight hours before UTC for much of the year, but seven hours before UTC during the summer; yet Los Angeles is always “Pacific time”.

If you set the time zone to "America/Sao_Paulo", times will be measured relative to Sao Paulo’s then-active time standard.